# Use the same word in each blank

Tags: word

One ___ girl went to the market and purchased ____. After returning to home she met with ______ boy. She got angry and left all her _____. The boy arranged the ____ and talked with the girl ____, ____ and took her to a restaurant.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, this is pretty confusing.

Comment: Is the bad grammar intentionally part of the puzzle? If not, it should be edited to make clear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something to do with

> day and date(s)?

I can't think of any words related to the tag *weighing* that fit in the blanks.